# Can one use native javascript/coffeescript constructors with the webOS Enyo framework?

Tags: javascript, coffeescript, palm, enyo

Palm's Enyo framework uses a DSL-ish "Kind" system to create objects based on prototypes. Unfortunately, this results in, what I believe to be, untidier code.

Does anyone have any experience using/hacking Enyo with native-javascript prototypes / constructors?

```
enyo.kind
  name:  'SimpleTimer'
  kind: "RowGroup"
  caption: "Simple Timer"
  published:
    timerDuration: 30
```

vs…

```
class SimpleTimer extends RowGroup
  caption: "SimpleTimer"
  published:
    timerDuration: 30
```

Hoping to know if anyone else has accomplished/attempted this.

Answer (score 1):

Not Enyo, but somewhat related, you might want to look into Jo if you want this style of coding. Here's a Coffeescript wrapper for it I saw yesterday:

http://k33g.github.com/2011/08/14/JO-COFFEESCRIPT.html

Jo works in webOS with PhoneGap, supports 1.x-3.x as well as other platforms. Cheers.

Answer (score 1):

I was trying to accomplish the same thing you are, using a different method of compiled Javascript (Haxe JS)

I was able to get this to work ... extending kinds like base classes, but I had to wrap the framework in my own files to get it to work. I don't wish that on anyone else, but feel free to take a peek at what I have working:

http://www.joshuagranick.com/blog/2011/08/08/enyo-with-code-completion-yes/

Have a great day!

Answer (score -1):

You can alternatively use a more functional, rather than object-oriented, style.  Maybe something like:

```
simpleTimer = (timerDuration) ->
  new RowGroup  caption: 'Simple Timer', timerDuration: timerDuration
```

And then instead of creating a timer by doing

```
new SimpleTimer timerDuration:99
```

you can do

```
simpleTimer 99
```

Comment: I realize I didn't address your question, instead I addressed the broader issue of whether you wanted object-oriented code, and the "untidiness" issue you mentioned.  I find that using Coffeescript is a natural match for a functional style of code.  I think that in many contexts my functional code example could be used in place of either of the two object-oriented alternatives in the question, and it is much shorter and IMHO less "untidy".